# ng-src not loading images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I load an image using `ng-src`? I am trying to swap the source of an image file from an `onclick` event using the following code but to no avail.

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <body>
        <pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <!--            Add DB names to label -->
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" ng-click="toggleImage()" btn-checkbox><img ng-src="{{imageSwapUrl}}"  />Left</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox><img id="dbIcon"  src="images/database-5-16.ico" />Middle</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox><img id="dbIcon"  src="images/database-5-16.ico" />Right</label>
        </div>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <script>
            angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
            angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.imageSwapUrl = "images/database-5-16.ico";
                $scope.checkModel = {
                    left: false,
                    middle: true,
                    right: false

                };
                $scope.toggleImage = function () {
                    if ($scope.imageSwapUrl === 'images/database-5-16.ico') {
                        $scope.imageSwapUrl = 'images/accept-database-16.ico';
                    } else {
                        $scope.imageSwapUrl = 'images/database-5-16.ico';
                    }
                }




            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The initial image file isn't being loaded when I run the above code but no errors are displayed in the console log, why would this be?

Comment: This might just be your example code, but "ButtonsCtrl" isn't being referenced anywhere, so the controller will not be invoked...

Comment: Can you share the errors that are displayed in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a controller `ButtonsCtrl` in javascript and never used it in your markup. so, the code inside the controller will never get called.

```
<body ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    .....
</body>
```

Comment: If this is the case, why would `<pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>` work?

Comment: if `$scope.checkModel` is defined in `ButtonsCtrl` controller, then yes.

Comment: You're right about this, but now i'm confused. Why does `{{checkModel}}` work when controller isn't defined in the mark-up yet `{{imageSwapUrl}}` doesn't is there a specific reason?? And thanks.

Comment: What do you mean `{{checkModel}}` works hen controller isn't defined? What is the output of `hen controller isn't defined` ?

Comment: Data was being printed depending on the button clicks i.e `left: true` but not quite as intended. Now its much better thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defined the controller define it

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dummydisc/disc/styles/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dummydisc/disc/scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    img#dbIcon {
      margin: -1px 0px 0px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 1px;
    }

    label.btn.btn-primary {
      width: 65px;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
  <pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <!--            Add DB names to label -->
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" ng-click="toggleImage()" btn-checkbox><img ng-src="{{imageSwapUrl}}" />Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox><img id="dbIcon" src="images/database-5-16.ico" />Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox><img id="dbIcon" src="images/database-5-16.ico" />Right</label>
  </div>
  <?php // put your code here ?>
  <script>
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.imageSwapUrl = "images/database-5-16.ico";
      $scope.checkModel = {
        left: false,
        middle: true,
        right: false

      };
      $scope.toggleImage = function() {
        if ($scope.imageSwapUrl === 'images/database-5-16.ico') {
          $scope.imageSwapUrl = 'images/accept-database-16.ico';
        } else {
          $scope.imageSwapUrl = 'images/database-5-16.ico';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHvJbQdUWUIzHu0KubYb?p=preview) this is not exactly your code